# Go package "database/sql" got the diff-result when use the same SQL-query

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")

    // Just Query
    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT id FROM test_1 WHERE id=123456")
    for rows.Next() {
        var id interface{}
        rows.Scan(&id)
        fmt.Println("Query no args =>", id)
    }

    // Query with args
    rows, _ = db.Query("SELECT id FROM test_1 WHERE id=?", 123456)
    for rows.Next() {
        var id interface{}
        rows.Scan(&id)
        fmt.Println("Query has args =>", id)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run main.go
Query no args => [49 50 51 52 53 54]
Query has args => 123456
```

Question:

In my mind, `"SELECT id FROM test_1 WHERE id=123456"` and `"SELECT id FROM test_1 WHERE id=?", 123456` are same SQL-query.

Why the result's TYPE is not same?

Is it a bug or just unfriendly API design?

Comment: Looks like a MySQL driver bug, not `database/sql`'s. Either way, you should almost never use `interface{}` when scanning results. If `id` is an integer, scan into `int64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to issue [#366](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/366). There are two protocols in MySQL:

1. **Text protocol**. When text protocol is used, regardless of column's type, the query result will be stored as `[]byte`. Related source code can be found at method [`textRows.readRow`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/26471af196a17ee75a22e6481b5a5897fb16b081/packets.go#L733). Further conversion will be done during [`rows.Scan`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) which is part of `database/sql` package. Here, the result will be converted (if convertible) from `[]byte` to the type of argument being passed to `Scan`.
2. Newer **binary protocol**. When this protocol is used, the query result will be converted to appropriate type based on column's type. Related source code can be found at [`binaryRows.readRow`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/26471af196a17ee75a22e6481b5a5897fb16b081/packets.go#L1143).

In this question, since the type of `Scan` argument is `interface{}`, in `database/sql` side, no conversion will occurs. When issuing a `query without args`, it seems that the driver will used *text protocol*, but when the query has argument(s), the driver will create prepared-statement then communicate to the server using *binary protocol*. In short:

1. Query no args: *text protocol* → result in `[]byte` → result scanned to `interface{}` → result is returned as ASCII code of `123456` (i.e. `[49 50 51 52 53 54]`).
2. Query with args: *binary protocol* → conversion based on column type (`int64`) → result scanned to `interface{}` → result returned as `int64`.

If you want to get same result, use the following code for first query (for clarity, error handling is omitted):

```
//Comment out
//rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT id FROM test_1 WHERE id=123456")

//then replace with
stmt, _ := db.Prepare("SELECT id FROM test_1 WHERE id=123456")
defer stmt.Close()
rows, _ := stmt.Query()
```